# Ionic Framework, A way to “post” or “send” a location?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, maps

First, I apologize if my English is confusing to you this time. This question sounds a little weird, maybe, but let me explain.

I have a contact form for request refueling of product; it is for commercial premises, such as restaurants. In this form, the customer chooses what product he needs, and where will be the delivery. When the customer fills all fields, these are send via post to a external server, that store the data and send after a email to the administrator. That works fine. But I have a new requirement, add a new field to form, which will be named "Location", and in this field the customer could add the location of the specific place where will be delivered the product, using Google Maps or Apple Maps.

So, I have two questions here:

1) What is the best way to obtain that data, and in a comfortable and clear way to the user. Is some plugin that I could use? The requirement specifies that it must be "like whatsapp functionality to share location", but I do not know if something like that can be done with Ionic, and also if it will works on android and ios, or even if any of the two cases have not installed the respective map application.

2) And, assuming I already have that location, what would be the best way to send such information in the post and mail to Administrator ? What do you recommend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a directive I wrote a while back. Please do note it's dependent on `angular-google-maps` package available [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/).

Also api might have changed so this should be considered a guidline only!

```js
angular.module('app.directives', [
    'uiGmapgoogle-maps'
  ])
  .directive('googlePlaces', function(uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        address: '=',
        coords: '='
      },
      template: '<input id="google_places_ac" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="input-block-level"/>',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        var listener;
        uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
          var autocomplete = new maps.places.Autocomplete(elm[0], {});

          listener = maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            if (place.geometry && scope.coords) {
              scope.coords.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
              scope.coords.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
            }

            scope.address = place.formatted_address;

            scope.$apply();
          });
        });

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
            if (listener)
              maps.event.removeListener(listener);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<!-- Usage -->
<google-places address="vm.address" [coords="vm.coords"]/>
```

As for saving the data: address string is better resolved but coordinates is more precise. It's your call how to save the location.